# Display Array Data through map in react Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I try to display Array data but does not display the data on the React web page. AnyOne guide me where is my mistake and correct me. **Please see the comment line //**

```
/* eslint-disable */

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';


class RestaurantList extends Component<{}, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { restoLists: null };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get("http://localhost:3030/restauranst")
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({ restoLists: response.data })
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.restoLists);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>RestaurantList</h1>
                {
                    this.state.restoLists ?
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                {
                                    this.state.restoLists.map((itme: any) => {
                                        console.log(itme.name); // work this line
                                        <li>
                                            {itme.name} {/**Does not work this line */}
                                        </li>
                                    })

                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        :
                    <p>Please Wait...</p>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RestaurantList;
```

**API Response**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pizza Hut",
      "address": "Dwarka Sector-14",
      "rating": "4.5",
      "email": "pizzhut@pizza.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mc-Dondle",
      "address": "Dwarka Sector-15",
      "rating": "4.0",
      "email": "mcdondle@mcdon.com"
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "expires": "-1",
    "pragma": "no-cache"
  },
  "config": {
    "url": "http://localhost:3030/restauranst",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

Comment: can you share your API response too?

Comment: Include the response data.

Comment: okay I will share you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not returning anything inside the map.

```
  this.state.restoLists.map(({id, name}: any) => {
           return <li key={id}>{name}</li>;
        });
```

Also you can use shorthand method of arrow function,

```
  this.state.restoLists.map(({id, name}: any) => <li key={id}>{name}</li>);
```

Comment: is using `any` in this situation ok? I am new to TS and wondering if we shouldn't define every single type of variable/param? for example, in this situation, should it not be `string` instead of `any`? just a question

Answer (score 1):

Return from your map function as you are missing return. and loader also try to use through state. By default make `isLoadding` to `false`

state

```
this.state = { restoLists: null, isLoadding : false };
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({isLoading: true})
        axios
        .get("http://localhost:3030/restauranst")
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ restoLists: response.data, isLoading: false})
        }).catch((error) => console.error(error));
 }
```

JSX

```
 const { restoLists } = this.state;
   return(
    <div>
    {isLoadding ? <ul>
        {restoLists && restoLists.map(({id, name}: any) => {
               return <li key={id}>{name}</li>;
            });
        }
       </ul>
     :<p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You were just missing **parenthesis** inside the return block of your map method:

```
 this.state.restoLists.map((itme: any) => {(
    <li>
        {itme.name}
    </li>
 )})
```